# Derivative of the product of a vector and its norm

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces

> I have a vector $\mathbf r$. A function of this vector is :
> $$
> \mathbf f = \|\mathbf r\|^2\mathbf r,
> $$
> where $\|\mathbf{r}\|$ represents the Euclidean norm of $\mathbf r$.
>
> I want to find $\frac{d\mathbf{f}}{d\mathbf{r}}$.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

$\textbf{r} = \{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\}$.

$\implies||\textbf{r}||^2 = r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2$

So

$\textbf{f}(1) = {r_1(r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2)}$

$\textbf{f}(2) = {r_2(r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2)}$

.

.

$\textbf{f}(n) = {r_n(r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2)}$

Therefore:
$\frac{d\textbf{f}}{d\textbf{r}} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}r_1^2\\r_2^2\\r_3^2\end{bmatrix}$

for a 3 element vector and the same concept can be extended to n-element vectors.

This however seems to be producing the incorrect answer. Is my idea here right? Or does it need any modifications?

Comment: shouldn't $\frac{df}{dt}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: What's your reasoning for that statement?

Comment: Because you are taking derivative of a "vector" w.r.t another "vector". For example, the first row of answer will be gradient of first element of $f$ w.r.t $r$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{Chain Rule:}\qquad \frac{d \|x\|^2 x}{d x} = 
\frac{\partial \|x\|^2 x}{\partial \|x\|^2}\frac{\partial \|x\|^2}{\partial x}
+\frac{\partial \|x\|^2 x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}
=2xx^T +\|x\|^2 I
$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a generalization of the product rule to this situation. If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and $V:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, then
$$
D(fV) = VDf + fDV.
$$
Note that $Df=\left(\nabla f\right)^T$ is a row vector, whereas $DV$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. We get
$$
D\left(\Vert x\Vert^2x\right)
= xD\left(\Vert x\Vert^2\right) + \Vert x\Vert^2Dx
= 2xx^T + \Vert x\Vert^2 I.
$$
This follows from your initial calculations too, but you should take the gradient of each coordinate function, i.e. work out $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ for each $i,j$. What you found was actually the diagonal of the real answer. You forgot the cases where $i\ne j$.